# How to share objects between activites, serialization or SingleInstance?

Tags: java, android

I have certain data in the data model class and want to share this data/object to the other activity. Single Instance could be a good choice but want to finish my previous activity and hence will got null pointer. Please Suggest the best possible way to do it?

Comment: just use static keyword before variable. And access it with classname.variable-name

Comment: @manish it's not a good practice, and if my activity got killed all static data will also not work. Static data will remain if object is there. Please provide correction if, i am wrong.

Comment: IN my case , all static data will alive while your application running, its not depend on activity lifecycle

Comment: yes,possible case if data doesn't belong to the activity.If the instance of activity that holding the data got killed, how the static data will alive. can use static class to hold the data but its not required and consume enough memory also. Any correction?

Comment: So your data is coming from activity (input) and related to activity lifecycle ?

Comment: yes, can use single static instance of activity to hold the objects and can use in other activity but have to finish the activity. User piyush suggest a good way to do it, I tried and its working fine. Thanks for your precious time manish.

Comment: Thanks for discussion and clear my doubts, I think we have to vote up answer of piyush. According to your problem Intent with putExtra will be the best way to solve your problem. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best possible way to use serialization, SingleInstance will not work here because you have to finish your activity.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, B.class);
ArrayList<String> data = new ArrayList<String>();
arrays.add("testing");
intent.putExtra("arrayList", data);
startActivity(intent);
```

you can use your objects instead of String and other side you can retrieve using this.

```
ArrayList<String> arrayList =(ArrayList<String>) getIntent().getSerializableExtra("arrayList");
```

Answer (score 1):

The best practice is to use intent object for that, putting either parcel or serialized data in his extras.

Static is dangerous since you must be always prepared for the case in which your application will be killed and restored.